# Start a different script as thread knowing script's name

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have 2 different python scripts, the first called `main.py` and the second called `running.py`

the `main.py` script is the following:

```
#setting things up and stuff
while True:
    #stuff
    Here running.py should be started
    #stuff
```

while `running.py` contains the following

```
#various imports
while True:
    #stuff
```

My question is, how can i run `running.py` from `main.py` as a new thread knowing only the name of the running script?

I looked a bit into it and, since i need to communicate and share data between `main.py` and `running.py`, I don't think creating a subprocess is the best course of action but I haven't found a way to run a whole script in a thread only knowing the script's name.

For various (stupid) company reasons I can't change the content of `running.py` and i can't import it into `main.py` so creating a threading class inside it is not a possibility but i have free rein on `main.py`

Is what i'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Sounds like [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) is what you need...

Comment: @Tomerikoo i need the two scripts to share memory space and as far as i know this is not possible with a subprocess

Comment: In that case, look at the second answer in the duplicate link which list alot of ways of doing what you need, and then consider using a thread with one of those methods as threads share memory

Comment: @Tomerikoo so you are saying something like starting a subprocess inside a thread from the main.py file so that, while being two different processes, they share memory because one is inside a child thread of the other? How ould one go about doing so? I really don't understand how it could be written so that it works.

Comment: First of all as a disclaimer I don't have much experience with those things and merely offering advice on how to continue research. What I meant is leave the `subprocess` option all together, and from the `main.py` create another *thread* that calls the sccript using for example `os.system` and that way they will share memory. Again, smply offering advice this is why it's a comment and not an answer...